# correct call for processing object field before saving to storage

Tags: django

The situation is this one: 
I have a model that contains a CharField text. This text should be processed before storing the object. It seems natural to do this processing in the save() method, overriding it in the model.

How can I make this big processing before saving it? may be calling to external API that makes the processing and return the new field for the object? is this sound inside the save() method?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can override `save` method of your model. Reference : [Overriding predefined model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

Remember to all `super(..)` to save data to db.

If you are processing data submitted to a form, better way would be to have `clean` method for the field. Reference [Form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)